# Sharepoint Web service and insert to SQL Database

Tags: sql, web-services, sharepoint

Basically there are two major tasks I want to accomplish (considering I am more or less a mobile app developer).

1. Create a web-service and deploy it on Sharepoint 2013 and this would be consumed by a Mobile device (over http/s. There would be couple of strings that I would post to the web-service)
2. On receiving the strings, I need to insert those to an existing SQL Database table.

Regards,
Nirav

Comment: Why would you want to do that? SharePoint isn't a database, Lists aren't tables and ListItems aren't rows. Unless your service needs access to SharePoint data you'd be better off hosting it independently.

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve and how is SharePoint involved? SP provides a REST API and OData support that allow you to read and create ListItems. Serving mobile devices was one of the reasons the APIs were created in the first place

Comment: I want to receive "Mobile Device Details" on the "Sharepoint" hosted environment. If I can deploy the web-service independent of the Sharepoint that would be fine as well. On the web-service invocation I want to insert the data to the sql tables.